# Various <li> links usage but only work one <li> link for navigation bar

Tags: html

Below is my HTML code for my navigation area. I'm using `<ul><li>` link to my other pages for "about me" and "my CV" link. But is only works once which means when I click on "about me" link, it loads and when I go back to clicking "my CV" link. Is not working.

```
<ul id="about">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Pics/aboutX.gif" alt="aboutX" width="58" height="80" border="0" /></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">about</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="Pics/aboutline.png" alt="aboutline" width="51" height="44" border="0" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="CV.html">cv</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Assuming you have a file named about.html and a file named CV.html in the same directory, and that the code snippet you provided is in both files, then your navigation links will work.  There is nothing wrong with your HTML.  If your set up is as I describe and it's not working, you need to provide more information about your set up so that we can help identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are hosting on a server which cares about the case of filenames?

You have have a file named cv.html but the link is CV.html (capitals)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by your question, that you are getting an HTTP 404 (Page Not Found) error response when you click on the CV link.  If you are getting a different error, please say so, because that would indicate a different problem.

Assuming you are getting the 404 error, your HTML is fine. The problem has more to do with the URLs of the links.

For example, if a web browser requests a web page with your navigation code and the URL for the page is http://mywebsite/mydir/mypage.html then the links in your navigation code would then point to these URLs:

about.html = http://mywebsite/mydir/about.html

CV.html = http://mywebsite/mydir/CV.html

**Based on the way you have written your HTML, make sure that *about.html* and *CV.html* are in the same directory (folder) on your web server.**

Also it's a good practice to make sure your code refers to those files in with the same case-sensitivity, so in other words captialize the filenames in code the same way you saved them.  Your web server might require the filenames are capitalized the same way.